# I need help for the following script (JavaScript)

Tags: php, javascript, html

hello i would like to make a script in JS that creates a textfield on any site that you implement and when somebody whats to search something they simply enter the keyword, hit enter and get redirected to my domain with the search results.

My question is:
Can I make JS that can get the words from the textfield and redirect to something like:
www.mydomain.com/getkeywords.php?keywords= [Something] ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any Javascript for that.

Just make an HTML `<form>` that points to your external URL with `method="GET"`.

```
<form action="getkeywords.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="keywords" />
</form>
```

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted. It's by far the best solution. Works on all browsers, even with JS disabled, and takes 3 seconds to implement.

Comment: I assumed that by "on any site that you implement", OP wanted to use javascript to generate the form by having the user link to a remote script. Not sure though.

Comment: I agree, if you can do it server side no need for JS.

Comment: @Madmartigan: What on earth for?

Comment: thank you man, i was thinking that much about JS that i forgot i don;t even need it!

Comment: I don't think this is what the TS wants. Read his first sentence again and have a look at my answer below. But maybe it's me that has misunderstood :-)
I indeed agree with Madmartigan, and SLaks; what on earth for? http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/jssyndicate/

Comment: @Richard Given that the OP said thanks, I think it's what he wanted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a JS file that runs on your server, and when implemented adds a `<form>` to the HTML of the page, where the JS is loaded from. You can do this using `document.write();`. You can set-up the form so that the `action` points to your website. You don't need to do anything special for the search on `enter`.
What you need to be aware of is that the source site may not have jQuery or any other library enabled. So try not to use jQuery, but alternatively you can test in the JS if jQuery has been loaded and if not, load it yourself.

Comment: `you can create a JS file that runs on your server` - really? New one on me, that... Unless your talking about Node or something... which I sort of doubt...

Comment: I think by "runs on your server" Richard meant "you host it and they include it via <script> tag".

Comment: Great comment Dave. Have a look here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/jssyndicate/

Comment: You can even reference a e.g. PHP or ASPX file trough Javascript to serve dynamic content on other sites/domains.

Comment: I now understand what you mean, but the word "runs" suggests that the Javascript is *executed* on the server, which it isn't. Swap "runs" for "is hosted" and it will clarify. And yes, I know I am an irritating pedant.